# Django Update of table doesn't work because of clean method in modelForm

Tags: django, forms, modelform

Here is my form

```
class TypeCompteForm(forms.Form):
    LIBELLES = (("xxxxx","xxxxxxx"),("xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx"))
    libelle = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,choices=LIBELLES,error_messages=err_msg,widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder": "Libellé du type"}))
    code = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder": "Code de du type"}))

    def clean_libelle(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["libelle"]
        if TypeMagasin.objects.filter(libelle=data).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Un type de magasin avec ce libellé existe déjà !")
        return data
```

With this form I manage to insert the data in the data base. But when I try to modify one record the clean_libelle method executes.
Below is the view I use for updating

```
def updateView(request,id):
    instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = ModelForm(instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ModelForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return render(request,"template.html")
    return render(request,"reconciliation/template.html",{"form":form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update view, the form instance is created twice. The first time it is created with `form = ModelForm(instance=instance)` and the second time it is created with `form = ModelForm(request.POST, instance=instance)`. The first time it is created, the `clean_libelle` method is not called. The second time it is created, the method is called, which raises the validation error. To fix this issue, you need to skip the validation of the `libelle` field if the instance already exists in the database. You can achieve this by manually setting the value of the `libelle` field in the form before calling the `is_valid` method. Here's the updated view code:

```
def updateView(request, id):
    instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = ModelForm(instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ModelForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if instance.libelle == form.cleaned_data["libelle"]:
            form.cleaned_data["libelle"] = instance.libelle
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return render(request, "template.html")
    return render(request, "reconciliation/template.html", {"form": form})
```